# Oracle APEX - how to show an item on page load based on the value of another item

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have an item on the page which I want to show/hide on page load based on the value of another item. If item2 is `Yes`, then show item1, or if item2 is `No`, then hide item1.

I know how to do that using dynamic action and javascript but I want to avoid using javascript. Is there a way to use APEX built-in functionality to do that? I know I can use `Show` action to hide an item, but I only need to show it if item2 is `Yes`. The APEX `Show` action does not have a condition

Also have the same issue with On Change event:

```
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var status = document.getElementById("status");

if (status.options[status.selectedIndex].text == "Completed") {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to set the status to Completed?");
    if (r == true) {
       apex.submit({request:'STATUS_CHANGE'}) 
    }

} else {

    result.value = "";
    $x("P2_THE_DATE").value = "";

    apex.submit({request:'STATUS_CHANGE'})
}

//set a value of a hidden field for status
 apex.item("P2_STATUS").setValue(status.options[status.selectedIndex].text);
```

Is there a better, more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

ITEM2 must get its value *on load* somehow, right? So, use the same code (that populates ITEM2) as a condition for ITEM1 and check whether its value is "Yes" (and display it) or "No" (so don't).

I prefer using a *function that returns a Boolean* to do so; something like

```
declare
  l_item2 varcahr2(10);
begin
  -- this is supposed to look like source for ITEM2
  select ...
    into l_item2
    from ...
    where ...;

  return l_item2 = 'Yes';
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! Looking into it

Comment: what about if it happens in On Change event? I added some code to the question

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that a perfect use case to incorporate js - to have a dynamic behavior on a web page. Why would you want to avoid it? I'm just curious.

Anyway, you could however achieve similar behavior, provided the item2 is a Select List or Radio Group.

- Set the 'Page Action on Selection' to Submit
- Set the source used to 'Only when current values is NULL' - so the value gets stored in the session even after submitting the page.
- Have the conditional display for item1 set as "ITEM is NOT NULL" and choose ITEM2 as the item.

If you follow these steps, the ITEM1 would show up after the selection of ITEM2.

Comment: Personally I am all for js, but there are some concerns with supporting it: not all developers are well versed in js plus when APEX is upgraded, there are concerns that js could become outdated